# Gradle plugins DSL block plugins not working for buildSrc

Tags: kotlin, gradle, plugins, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am discovering the new `plugins` declaration in `Gradle`. First applying below in the root `Gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "7.2" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "7.2" apply false
}
```

instead of

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
```

And I also need the `Gradle` plugin in `buildSrc` so I have below in there, too

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        register("LibraryCommonPlugin") {
            id = "libraryCommonPlugin"
            implementationClass = "LibraryCommonPlugin"
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(libs.plugin.android)
    compileOnly(libs.plugin.kotlin)
    implementation(libs.plugin.gradleVersions)

    implementation(libs.kotlin)

    compileOnly(gradleApi())
    compileOnly(localGroovy())
}
```

And I have a common `Gradle` file that applies the plugin in child modules if is used

**android_defaults.gradle**

```
apply from: "$rootDir/buildsystem/helper.gradle"
apply plugin: "libraryCommonPlugin"

android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...
```

**app/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")

    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

apply(from = "../buildsystem/android_defaults.gradle")
```

but then IDE throws an exception when I try to build

> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script.
> com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin

Problems occuring from this custom plugin

```
class LibraryCommonPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        target.plugins.all { plugin ->
            when (plugin) {
                is AppPlugin -> target.configureAndroid()
                is LibraryPlugin -> target.configureLibrary()
                is KotlinBasePluginWrapper -> target.configureWithKotlinPlugin()
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun Project.configureAndroid() {
        androidDependencies()
        baseKotlinModuleDependencies()
        extensions.getByType<AppExtension>().configure()
    }

    private fun Project.configureLibrary() {
        androidDependencies()
        baseKotlinModuleDependencies()
        extensions.getByType<LibraryExtension>().configure()
    }

    private fun Project.configureWithKotlinPlugin() {
        baseKotlinDependencies()
        tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
            this.kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
        }
    }
}

private fun BaseExtension.configure() {
    setCompileSdkVersion(ProjectConfig.compileSdkVersion)

    with(defaultConfig) {
        minSdk = ProjectConfig.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = ProjectConfig.targetSdkVersion
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    with(compileOptions) {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
    }
}

private fun Project.androidDependencies() {
    commonAndroidDependencies()
}

private fun Project.commonAndroidDependencies() {
    dependencies {
        add("coreLibraryDesugaring", Dependencies.Tools.desugarJdkLibs)
    }
}

private const val IMPLEMENTATION = "implementation"
private const val LINT_CHECKS = "lintChecks"

private fun Project.baseKotlinDependencies() {
    dependencies {
        add(IMPLEMENTATION, Dependencies.Base.kotlin)
        add(IMPLEMENTATION, Dependencies.Base.kotlinReflect)
    }
}

private fun Project.baseKotlinModuleDependencies() {
    dependencies {
        add(LINT_CHECKS, project(Dependencies.Modules.Base.customLint))
    }
}
```

So how can I have the `Gradle` plugin works for the both places?

Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to work out what's going on from those small snippets, more information would be helpful. Please update your question to include the root `build.gradle.kts`, `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, and any convention plugins.

Comment: Hello @aSemy, updated the question. No much change in the root `Gradle` file. Added `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` and the custom plugin class in where most problems occur. IDE throws that `AppExtension`, `LibraryExtension`, `AppPlugin`, etc not found

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite clear on what's going on though. So you've written your own convention plugin `./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/LibraryCommonPlugin.kt`? Do you have a [`gradlePlugin { }` block](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) in `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`? Are you applying your custom plugin to a subproject? What's the full stacktrace? What are the full dependency coordinates?

Comment: Hey @aSemy, yes I have the `gradlePlugin` block in `./buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` and a common `Gradle` script that applies this plugin to child modules accordingly, sorry my bad I didn't add them. So now I edited the question I have more things in there. Could you please take a look again? Stacktrace is too long please find in here: https://pastebin.com/qtA78jUk

Comment: Thanks. `apply(from = "../buildsystem/...)` looks very strange to me. What is the `buildsystem` dir? Why are you using `apply(from=...)`? I think you need to compare what you have with what the docs demonstrate: [Use `buildSrc` to abstract imperative logic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) and [Sharing build logic between subprojects Sample](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html)

Comment: i have same problem. LIbraryExtension not found. do you have resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.
Try to replace

```
compileOnly(libs.plugin.android)
compileOnly(libs.plugin.kotlin)
```

with

```
implementation(libs.plugin.android)
implementation(libs.plugin.kotlin)
```